# Launch a radio app as my alarm for android

Tags: java, android, broadcastreceiver, alarmmanager, internet-radio

First time posting.

I want to make an alarm app that launches a radio app at the set alarm time.

The app works fine when the phone is awake, the radio app launches and the radio plays at the time specified by the alarm, my issue is when the phone is locked/asleep, the radio app I want to launch will launch but not attempt to connect to the radio stream until I unlock the phone. When I unlock the phone the app is open and starts to buffer then works.

How do I get the app to connect to the radio stream while the phone is asleep?

I have tried WakeLocks (Partial WakeLocks) thinking that keeping the CPU alive would allow the app to connect to its radio stream but this did not work.

Would appreciate any input here.

EDIT: I have downloaded an app that does what i want and it seems the radio plays within the notification.

Would this be the correct direction to investigate?

Answer (score 0):

Well, I figured it out after eventually.

using media player and connecting to the correct steam sorted it for me.

For anyone struggling:

1. Main activity you want to create all the actions for the button clicks, build an Intent and get the time from the time picker.
2. Alarm receiver to handle the pending Intent
3. Radio service class to play radio stream using Media player.

It actually was very simple in the end.

one of the things that was holding me up was the incorrect use of the stream source I was using:

I was trying: http://www.lbc.co.uk/london/radio/player/
I needed: http://www.lbc.co.uk/london/radio/player/
I obtain the correct streaming link from FAQs on the radio website.

I will post a finished sample code once I have done cleaning the app.